# How to get Texturing work with OpenGL's glDrawElements, interleaved Array, VBO and VAO?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, vbo

What I want to do is to render an interleaved vertex array with the help of VBO and VAO. Unfortunately the scene shows no textures, only regular grey triangles. Yet all vertex positions seem to be correctly drawn. I'm almost inclined to think that the problem is a wrong index or attribute setting but after reading a lot of questions here about glVertexAttribPointer's Stride and Pointer parameters I've double checked that. To exclude issues with data structures and other stuff I tried to render everything with glBegin/glTexCoord2f/glVertex3f/glEnd and it works fine(but very slow).

My class members:

```
vector<unsigned short>  m_indexVec;
vector<PackedVertex>    m_vertVec;
GLuint                  m_textureId;
GLuint                  m_vboIdVertex;
GLuint                  m_vboIdIndex;
GLuint                  m_vao;
```

My vertex structure:

```
struct PackedVertex
{
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec2 uv;
    glm::vec3 normal;
}
```

VAO/VBO Init:

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vao);

glBindVertexArray(m_vao);
glGenBuffers(1, &m_vboIdVertex);
glGenBuffers(1, &m_vboIdIndex);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vboIdVertex);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vboIdIndex);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(PackedVertex), (const GLvoid *)(offsetof(PackedVertex,position)) );  // vertices
glEnableVertexAttribArray((GLuint)0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(PackedVertex), (const GLvoid *)(offsetof(PackedVertex,uv)) );        // uv
glEnableVertexAttribArray((GLuint)1);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(PackedVertex), (const GLvoid *)(offsetof(PackedVertex,normal)) );    // normals
glEnableVertexAttribArray((GLuint)2);



glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(PackedVertex) * m_vertVec.size(), &m_vertVec[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned short) * m_indexVec.size(), &m_indexVec[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Render method:

```
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textureId );
glBindVertexArray(m_vao);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, m_indexVec.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (const GLvoid*)0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330
in vec4 vVertex;
in vec2 vTexCoords;
uniform mat4 mvp;
smooth out vec2 uv;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = mvp * vVertex;
    uv = vTexCoords;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330
in vec2 uv;
uniform sampler2D colortexture;
out vec4 vFragColor;
void main()
{
    vFragColor = texture(colortexture, uv.st);
}
```

After activating the shaders:

```
GLint t = glGetUniformLocation(UVShader, "colortexture");
glUniform1i(t, textureUnit);

glm::mat4 glm_PModelViewMatrix = glm_ProjectionMatrix * glm_ViewMatrix;
GLint MVPLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderPrograms[ShaderNames::UVShader], "mvp");
gluniformmatrix4fv(MVPLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(glm_PModelViewMatrix) );
```

Now I changed my shaders to:

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330                            
layout (location=0) in vec4 vVertex;    
layout (location=1) in vec2 vTexCoords; 
uniform mat4 mvp;                       
smooth out vec2 uv;                     
void main()                             
{                                       
    gl_Position = mvp * vVertex;        
    uv = vTexCoords;                    
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 330                            
in vec2 uv;                             
uniform sampler2D colortexture;         
out vec4 vFragColor;                        
void main()                                 
{
    vFragColor = texture(colortexture, uv.st);
}
```

...but I see no changes when I use the "layout" feature. Everything is textured just like before, but the problem with my access violation remains (only in the release build). I think it's still a problem with data copied around by glBufferData or accessed by glDrawElements.

Comment: How does your fragment shader look like? How do you load textures and assign them to sampler uniforms?

Comment: Along the same lines of what @datenwolf is asking: How do you ensure that your vertex attribute locations match up with the corresponding attribute inputs in the vertex shader?

Comment: Your vertex shader texcoord output does not match the input of the fragment shader, `smooth out vec2 uv;` vs. `in vec4 uv;`. This shouldn't even link. Also, you still have not explained how you define the attribute locations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @datenwolf and Reto Koradi. This pointed me in the right direction. Now the textures seem to be drawn correctly in debug build but I get an access violation in my release build: Unhandled exception at 0x69341707 in foo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000. I know everything in my program could have caused this.. Any ideas?

Comment: @RetoKoradi how can I ensure that the vertex attributes find their way to the shader? The problem also is that I have old OpenGL code mixed with new features (I use the compatibility profile) and I'm not sure if everything makes sense in the way I do it :)

Comment: The easiest way is to specify the location directly in the shader code. You can change your `in` declarations to: `layout (location=0) in vec4 vVertex;` and `layout (location=1) in vec2 vTexCoords;` to set the locations to the values you use in your code.